# Detox v18 upgrade - App has not responded to the network requests below: (id = -1000) isReady: {}

Tags: expo, detox

I am running Detox with Expo.

Prior to upgrading to v18 of detox, I used to get the following error:

```
detox[7528] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

That might be the reason why the test "your test" has timed out.
```

I managed to fix this issue by following the fix provided here: https://github.com/expo/detox-tools/issues/1#issuecomment-740675824. (tl;dr, make some changes to the detox expo helpers in node modules).

After upgrading to Detox 18.0.1, I have made the amendments noted in the v18.0.0 migration release (specifically to the custom detox environment class). But, I am now getting the same error as above. I have reverted the changes made in the node modules (mentioned above) and still no luck.

I have the following related packages:

```
    "detox": "^18.0.1",
    "detox-expo-helpers": "^0.6.0",
    "expo": "^38.0.0",
    "expo-detox-hook": "^1.0.10",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-circus": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^39.0.0",
```

Comment: Please try 18.0.2. We had an issue in 18.0.1 and it was reverted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for Detox 18.x.x you would need to follow [migration guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Migration.md), otherwise you will have your app hanging on launch.